# Correos se envían a la dirección incorrecta

Tags: php, phpmailer

Se me presentó un problema con el envío de correos con PHPMailer. Tengo un script que envía un correo electrónico a cada uno de los clientes seleccionados mediante checkbox, el problema es que si por ejemplo selecciono 3 clientes, a cada cliente le llegan 3 correos de los 3 seleccionados, en vez de que le llegue un solo correo al cliente correspondiente. Es como si la variable `$array[0]` almacenara los 3 correos electrónicos.

Les dejo mi código para ver si me pueden ayudar a encontrar mi error.

config.php

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
    
//Server settings
$mail->isSMTP();                            //Send using SMTP
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                  //Enable implicit TLS encryption
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                       //Enable verbose debug output
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com';   //Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                   //Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 587;    
$mail->Username   = '*********'             //SMTP username
$mail->Password   = '*********';            //SMTP password
```

modal-suspend-service.php (donde tengo un checkbox por cada cliente y el botón que activa el servicio y manda correo)

```
    <form method="post">    
        <?php 
        foreach ($execute_suspended_services as $row) { 
        ?>
        <div class="form-row bg-light rounded mb-1 p-2 align-items-center">
            <input class="mr-2" type="checkbox" name="select[]" id="select" onChange="disableSending();" value="<?php echo $row['idCustomerPackage']; ?>">
            <a href="services-by-user.php?idCustomer=<?php echo $row['idCustomer'] ?>&idCustomerType=1" class="mb-0 text-gns" style="font-size: 14px;"><b><?php echo $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['lastname']; ?></b></a>
            <div class="spinner-grow spinner-grow-sm text-danger ml-2" role="status">
                <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
        <div class="text-center mb-2 mt-4 <?php echo $btn_active; ?>">
            <button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-success col-12 col-sm-4 active_service" name="btnActiveService" id="btnActiveService" disabled><i class="fas fa-check mr-2"></i> Activar</button>
        </div>
   </form>
```

suspend-service-backend.php

```
if (isset($_POST['btnActiveService'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['select'] as $idService) {

        //Por cada checkbox seleccionado, hago un select para obtener el correo del cliente
        $get_customer = "SELECT customers.email FROM customers INNER JOIN customers_packages ON customers.idCustomer = customers_packages.idCustomer WHERE id_customerPackage = '$idService'";
        $execute_get_customer = mysqli_query($connection, $get_customer);
        
        //Array para obtener el correo del cliente por índice $array[0]
        $array = mysqli_fetch_row($execute_get_customer);

        //Hago update para activar el servicio al cliente seleccionado
        $active_service = "UPDATE customers_packages SET is_active = 1 WHERE id_customerPackage = '$idService'";
        $execute_active_service = mysqli_query($connection, $active_service);

        $message = "servicio activado";

        if (!$execute_active_service) {
            echo "<script>alert('Ha ocurrido un error al activar el servicio, favor de contactar al desarrollador');
            window.location.href = '" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "';
            </script>";
        } else {
            try {
                $mail->setFrom('*************', 'CS (NO RESPONDER)');
                //array[0] contiene el correo del cliente
                $mail->addAddress($array[0]);
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->Subject = "Servicio activado";
                $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
                $mail->Body = $message;
                $mail->send();

                echo "<script>alert('El servicio se ha activado correctamente');
                window.location.href = '" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "';
                </script>";
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "<script>alert('El servicio se ha activado correctamente, pero ha ocurrido un error al notificar al cliente.');
                window.location.href = '" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "';
                </script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano amigos!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe a que en cada iteración agregas más destinatarios a la instancia creada (eg: `$mail = new PHPMailer()`).

#### Solución:

Luego de realizar el envío tenes que llamar a [`clearAddresses()`](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#method_clearAddresses)

**Ejemplo:**

```php
// ... código
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->send();
$mail->clearAddresses() ; // Acá

//... más código
```

Comment: ¡Funcionó! Muchas gracias amigo Marcos.

Answer (score 1):

¿Dónde defines la variable `$mail`? Antes del ciclo, ¿cierto? PhpMailer conserva la información y, en teoría, al seleccionar 3 clientes, el primero recibe 3 correos, el segundo dos y el tercero solo uno, porque se van agregando las direcciones en cada iteración del ciclo.

La variable `$array[0]` siempre tiene solo una dirección, pero el método `$mail->addAddress()` hace que PhpMailer guarde internamente las direcciones a donde se enviará el correo:

Primera iteración:

- Correo de cliente 1, solo lo recibe cliente 1

Segunda iteración:

- Correo de cliente 1 y cliente 2, lo reciben ambos

Tercera iteración:

- Correo de cliente 1 + cliente 2 + cliente 3, lo reciben los 3

Inicializa la variable antes del bloque `try ... catch` para evitar que se acumulen las direcciones:

```
// Inicializar dentro del ciclo
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    $mail->setFrom('*************', 'CS (NO RESPONDER)');
    // array[0] contiene el correo del cliente
    // Solo se va a agregar el correo actual
    $mail->addAddress($array[0]);
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "Servicio activado";
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->send();

    echo "<script>alert('El servicio se ha activado correctamente');
    window.location.href = '" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "';
    </script>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<script>alert('El servicio se ha activado correctamente, pero ha ocurrido un error al notificar al cliente.');
    window.location.href = '" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "';
    </script>";
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Añadí la línea antes del try...catch pero ahora no envía ningún correo, y si selecciono 3 clientes sólo hace el update al primero y los otros dos los ignora como si no los hubiera seleccionado.

Comment: @EdgarSaavedra, modifica tu código para mostrar [todos los errores](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-SMTP.html#constant_DEBUG_LOWLEVEL) y agrega la salida en tu pregunta.